# WordPress: ReferenceError jQuery on YITH POS page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add jQuery to the javascript.js file for a child of woodmart theme, but I keep getting "javascript.js:131 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

javascript.js

```html
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         //cart_actions parent container
        //for POST requests when user saves a cart
        clickparent = document.querySelector(".cart-actions");
        clickparent.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // e = event object
            let carts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('yithPOS_carts'));
            if (e.target && (e.target.className == "cart-action cart-action--suspend-and-save-cart cart-action--with-icon") || e.target.className == "cart-action__icon yith-pos-icon-saved-cart") {
            // Use ajax to do something...
            var postData = {
                action: 'wpa_49691',
                my_var: 'carts',
            }
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                dataType:"json",
                url: youruniquejs_vars.ajaxurl,
                //This fires when the ajax 'comes back' and it is valid json
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("Cart saved to database.");
                }
                //This fires when the ajax 'comes back' and it isn't valid json
            }).fail(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
        });
    
        //pos_current_Cart_buttons parent container
        //for GET requests when user views saved carts
        viewcartparent = document.querySelector(".yith-pos-cart__buttons");
        viewcartparent.addEventListener("click", function(e) { // e = event object
            if (e.target && (e.target.className == "yith-pos-cart__buttons-saved-carts")) {
                // Use ajax to do something...
            var getData = {
                action: 'wpa_49692',
                my_var: 'my_data',
            }
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: getData,
                dataType:"json",
                url: youruniquejs_vars.ajaxurl,
                //This fires when the ajax 'comes back' and it is valid json
                success: function (response) {
                    let total;
                    for(item in response){
                        total += item[lineTotal];
                    }
                    $(".yith-pos-cart__savedcarts").append('</div><i class="yith-pos-cart__savedcart"></i><div class="cart-saved__name"><div class="cart-saved__name__id">' + response['id'] + '</div><div class="cart-saved__name__customer">' + response['cartitems']['names'] + '</div></div><div class="cart-saved__num_of_items">' + response['cartitems'].size + '</div><div class="cart-saved__status">Pending Payment</div><div class="cart-saved__total">'+ total + '</div><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="yith-pos-icon-refresh"></i> load</button></div>');
                }
                //This fires when the ajax 'comes back' and it isn't valid json
            }).fail(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }); 
        }
        });
        // Handler for .ready() called.
      });
})(jQuery);
```

I've also tried enqueuing jquery with wp_enqueue_script and passing jquery in an array to the javascript file, neither changed anything.
functions.php:

```html
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
//First enqueue your javascript in WordPress
function save_cart_enqueue_scripts(){

    //Enqueue your Javascript (this assumes your javascript file is located in your plugin in an "includes/js" directory)
    wp_enqueue_script( 'javascript.js', plugins_url('https://cigarchiefstg.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/woodmart-child/yith-pos-additions/javascript.js', dirname(__FILE__) ), array( 'jQuery' ));

    //Here we create a javascript object variable called "youruniquejs_vars". We can access any variable in the array using youruniquejs_vars.name_of_sub_variable
    wp_localize_script( 'javascript', 'javascript_vars', 
        array(
            //To use this variable in javascript use "youruniquejs_vars.ajaxurl"
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'javascript_vars.ajaxurl' ),
        ) 
    );  

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'save_cart_enqueue_scripts' );

//This is your Ajax callback function
function cart_save_callback_function(){

    //Get the post data 
    $my_var = $_POST["my_var"];

    //Do your stuff here - maybe an update_option as you mentioned...
    update_option('saved_carts', $my_var);

    //Create the array we send back to javascript here
    $return_array = array();

    //Make sure to json encode the output because that's what it is expecting
    echo json_encode( $return_array );

    //Make sure you die when finished doing ajax output.
    die(); 
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . 'wpa_49691', 'cart_save_callback_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . 'wpa_49691', 'cart_save_callback_function' );


function cart_view_callback_function(){

    //Get the post data 
    $my_var = $_POST["my_var"];

    //Do your stuff here - maybe an update_option as you mentioned...

    //Create the array we send back to javascript here
    $carts = get_option('saved_carts');

    //Make sure to json encode the output because that's what it is expecting
    echo json_encode( $carts );

    //Make sure you die when finished doing ajax output.
    die(); 
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . 'wpa_49692', 'cart_view_callback_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . 'wpa_49692', 'cart_view_callback_function' );
```

Edit: Issues with POS items:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check if jquery is correctly loaded on you wp website.

I suggest using this syntax for jQuery:

```
 (function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //your code
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok, I checked using an alert with if(window.jQuery) to see if jQuerys been loaded in the window and it hasn't been. It gives the same error with the code you provided also.  So how can I go about loading it?

Comment: Try insert your jquery code directly in the functions.php of your child theme, and see what happens.
You can use 'wp_head' hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/

Comment: Looks like jquerys loading now, thank you (:

Comment: Sorry, another issue came up. add_action('wp_head', 'myfunc') doesn't seem to be loading my javascript in the header.  do_action('wp_head') does the trick, but causes issues with the rest of the page loading.

Comment: what kind of issues?

Comment: edited to include a screenshot, POS items aren't showing up and are instead just grayed boxes.

Comment: you should check dev console and see the returned errors